# Need help web scraping a table

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to web scraping and trying to scrape 16k rows of this table, https://www.levantineceramics.org/vessels, but the table rows are inside a tbody and standard web scraping methods using pandas and beautiful soup do not work, as they show up blank (Empty Dataframe) or (['<tbody></tbody>]).

I tried looking at web scraping tutorials for pandas, beautiful soup, and selenium and wasn't successful. Is it even possible to scrape this table and if so, could you push me in the right direction?

Here is my code showing the result of :
[<tbody>

</tbody>]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://www.levantineceramics.org/vessels'
page = requests.get(url)
data = bs(page.text, "html.parser")
table = data.body.findAll('tbody')
print(table)
```

Answer (score 2):

The data is loaded from external URL via Javascript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can try to get data from their Ajax API via requests:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://www.levantineceramics.org/vessels/datatable.json"

params = {
    "sEcho": "2",
    "iColumns": "12",
    "sColumns": ",,,,,,,,,,,",
    "iDisplayStart": "0",
    "iDisplayLength": "100",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

# create <table> and parse it through pandas

columns = [
    "ID",
    "Vessel registration number",
    "Vessel photos",
    "Vessel drawings",
    "Shape",
    "Functional category",
    "Date BCE/CE",
    "Period",
    "Site Name",
    "Country/region",
    "Contributors",
    "Action",
]

table = ["<tr>" + "\n".join(f"<th>{cell}</th>" for cell in columns) + "</tr>"]
for row in data["aaData"]:
    table.append("<tr>" + "\n".join(f"<td>{cell}</td>" for cell in row) + "</tr>")


df = pd.read_html("<table>" + "\n".join(table) + "</table>")[0]
print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| ID | Vessel registration number | Vessel photos | Vessel drawings | Shape | Functional category | Date BCE/CE | Period | Site Name | Country/region | Contributors | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Mizpe Yammim 19/165 | View | View | Juglet | Cosmetic/Toilette/Medicine | 5th-4th centuries BCE | Achaemenid Persian | Mizpe Yammim | Israel/Galilee | Andrea M. BerlinRafael Frankel | nan |
| 8 | Mizpe Yammim 22/452 | View | View | Juglet | Cosmetic/Toilette/Medicine | 5th-4th century BCE | Achaemenid Persian | Mizpe Yammim | Israel/Galilee | Andrea M. BerlinRafael Frankel | nan |
| 9 | Mizpe Yammim 8/398 | View | View | Juglet | Cosmetic/Toilette/Medicine | 5th-4th century BCE | Achaemenid Persian | Mizpe Yammim | Israel/Galilee | Rafael FrankelAndrea M. Berlin | nan |
| 10 | Qedesh K00P168 | View | nan | Cooking pot | Cooking/Food production | 3rd-mid-2nd c. BCE | Hellenistic | Qedesh | Israel/Galilee | Peter J. StoneAndrea M. Berlin | nan |
| 11 | Qedesh K00P058 | View | nan | Casserole/Lopas | Cooking/Food production | 2nd c. BCE | Middle Hellenistic | Qedesh | Israel/Galilee | Peter J. StoneAndrea M. Berlin | nan |
| 14 | Miqne INE.4.392/1 | View | nan | Bowl, large | Household/Utility | 1200BCE - 1150BCE | Iron Age I | Tel Miqne/Ekron | Israel/Shephelah | nan | nan |
| 16 | Qedesh K09P046 | View | nan | Saucer | Dining/Drinking/Serving | 300 BCE - 150 BCE | Middle Hellenistic | Qedesh | Israel/Galilee | Peter J. StoneAndrea M. Berlin | nan |
| 17 | Qedesh K00P157 | View | View | Plate | Dining/Drinking/Serving | 200 BCE - 140 BCE | Middle Hellenistic | Qedesh | Israel/Galilee | Peter J. Stone | nan |
| 18 | Tel Anafa PW 49/TA79P49 | View | View | Juglet | Cosmetic/Toilette/Medicine | 5th-4th c. BCE | Achaemenid Persian | Tel Anafa | Israel/Hula Valley | Andrea M. Berlin | nan |
| 19 | Mizpe Yammim 15/362 | View | View | Juglet | Cosmetic/Toilette/Medicine | 5th-4th century BCE | Achaemenid Persian | Mizpe Yammim | Israel/Galilee | Andrea M. BerlinRafael Frankel | nan |

Comment: If i remove your head() function, I get the first 100 rows. How would you go about getting the next 100 rows, and so on.

Comment: @Françoisd'Entremont Change the `"iDisplayStart"` param to `"100"` and do the request again. Then increase the parameter and repeat.

Comment: Ideally I would like to scrape the images and also the coordinates located in the action column. The images are nested inside a pop up window and sometimes there are multiple in a gallery. And for the coordinates, it brings you to a map where the developer tools will show the coordinates. I don't think we could get the coordinates since it's on a different page. How would you get the image information from their API?

Comment: @Françoisd'Entremont Maybe you can see, if the information is inside the `data` returned from the server. Try to `print(data)`.